# Replace NULL in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm using 2 lookups in ssis for 2 tables. If a column is null in the other table, im going to use the other value and vice versa.
how to implement this one?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use your look up component, and add the new column (*Correspondant value in Lookup Table*)

*Assuming that your columns names are `LookupColumn1` and `LookupColumn2` And `OutColumn` is the expected output column:*

**First Method**

- Add a **script component**
- Mark `LookupColumn1` and `LookupColumn2` as Input
- Add an Output Column  `OutColumn` *( DataType: DT_STR or DT_WSTR)*
- In your Script Write the following Code (*inside ProcessInputRow Sub*) :

  ```
  Public Overrides Sub InputBuffer0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As InputBuffer0) 

      If Not Row.LookUpColumn2_IsNull AndAlso _
         Not String.IsnullOrEmpty(Row.LookUpColumn2.Trim) Then

          Row.OutColumn = Row.LookUpColumn2.Trim

      ElseIf Not Row.LookupColumn1_IsNull AndAlso _
         Not String.IsnullOrEmpty(Row.LookupColumn1.Trim) Then

          Row.OutColumn = Row.LookupColumn1.Trim

      Else 

          Row.OutColumn_IsNull = True

      End If

  End Sub
  ```

*Script Logic: If `LookupColumn2` is not null or empty, it's value is assigned to `OutColumn` , if `LookupColumn2` is null or empty we checks the value of `LookupColumn1` : if it is not null or empty, it's value is assigned to `OutColumn` , else `OutColumn` is NULL*

**Second Method**

Create a `derrived column` with the following expression

```
REPLACENULL(LookupColumn2,LookupColumn1)
```

Read more about `REPLACENULL` In this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh479601.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one idea how to do it:

Lookup component:

Add the column of the other table as a new column (like 'column2').

After the lookup put a derived column:

Derived column name will be your initial column, set it to replace the original column.

In the expression put:

```
REPLACENULL(column,column2)
```

Comment: if `column` is null there is no value in `column2`. `NULL` is excluded from lookup